# How to determine if an incoming url Request to an Openshift python 3.3 app is 'http' or 'https'?

Tags: python, https, request, openshift

How do you determine if an incoming url Request to an Openshift app is 'http' or 'https'?  I wrote an Openshift python 3.3 app back in June '13. I was able to tell if the incoming url to my Openshift app was 'http' or 'https' by the following code:

```
if request['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https':     #do something
```

This code no longer works when I create new Openshift apps.   I have posted on the Openshift forums without finding the solution.  They suggested that I post here.

Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug and will be fixed.

EDIT: Opened https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1048331 to track

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found that this works.

if request.environ['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'http':  # or https